# Secure HTTPS session over insecure HTTPS proxy in Golang

Tags: go, http, security, ssl, proxy

how to replicate in Go `curl --proxy-insecure` behavior given that

- `insecureproxy.net` has self signed certificate,
- `somesecureurl.net` has correct and trusted certificate?

```bash
https_proxy="https://insecureproxy.net" curl https://somesecureurl.net/ --proxy-insecure
```

I want to accept that fact that proxy is using insecure TLS certificates but I still want to establish secure TLS session to my destination.

I've attempted to use [`net/http`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http) but I can only disable TLS verification to **both** proxy and destination with `InsecureSkipVerify`.

```golang
c.Client = &http.Client{
    Transport: &http.Transport{
        TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{
            InsecureSkipVerify: true
        },
        Proxy: http.ProxyURL(insecureproxy),
    },
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set you client Transport to use both Transport.TLSClientConfig and Transport.DialTLSContext. In this case TLSClientConfig should be used for connections to destination HTTPS server and DialTLSContext - for connection to your HTTPS proxy.

In your case, it might look like this:

```
c.Client = &http.Client{
    Transport: &http.Transport{
        TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{
            // configs for destination server or nil to use defaults
        },
        Proxy: http.ProxyURL(insecureproxy),
        DialTLSContext: func(_ context.Context, network, addr string) (net.Conn, error) {
            return tls.Dial(network, addr, &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true})
        },
    },
}
```